# Organizing Nightly IMDB Dumps Into Structured Data

Tags: .net, sql, import

I'm currently trying to write a website for testing / learning purposes that will wrap around the [IMDB datasets that are dumped](http://www.imdb.com/interfaces#plain).

I'm having trouble determining the best way to extract the data into a format that is easier to manage. I will need to pull data from several files:

- movies.list = Movie list of all movies and year of production
- mpaa-ratings-reasons.list = MPAA ratings
- running-times.list = Running times

The data in these tables are linked by a unique name that is given to each line.  Essentially, I will need to join the lines of each of these text files together using the unique name.  After doing this, I will need to parse the data I need out of the actual unique name since the movie title isn't listed explicitly.  The unique name also specifies if the entry is a video game or TV show, which I will not be collecting data for.

Pulling the data from those unique name qualifiers is most likely going to be a Regex nightmare, but I'm more concerned with what the best method is for actually grouping the text files into a manageable format somewhere...  Should I...

1. Pull the data into staging tables on the SQL server, and then write a separate part in my app to join the tables and pull everything together?
2. Load the lines from the text files into a .NET data table and do my processing that way?

   1. In doing so, am I going to cause a memory nightmare for the box that is running this app?
3. Some other alternative?

On a side note, the movies.list file alone contains over 1 million lines of data.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Staging tables on the DB server, scrub the data into final tables.

If this means loading back into a client app for the processing, so be it.

Practically, a DB server will handle the quantity of data but SQL Server may not be the best for your processing.